# Expected ARIA "role" for non-interactive elements (tabIndex="-1")

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, tabindex

I'm writing a component for a web application where I need to explicitly prevent an element from gaining focus on "tab" press.

According to [W3c's specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute) I set `tabIndex` attribute to `-1` to declare non-interactive elements.

Now I wonder what is the [ARIA role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques) expected for such non-interactive element?

```
<div
    role="???"
    tabIndex="-1"
    onKeyDown="/* ... */"
    onClick="/* ... */"
>
    Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: If it's non-interactive why does it have both keydown and click events attached to it?  The users for whom ARIA roles exist won't be able to trigger those events if the element can't be put into focus.

Comment: It's a special component meant to stop events propagation when clickable elements are nested. https://github.com/MiroDojkic/react-clickable/blob/v1.0.0/src/components/StopPropagation/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, if the element cannot receive focus, it does not need a role.  That's not a general rule, though.  There are lots of elements that can't receive keyboard focus but still have a valid role, such as headings, lists, and tables.  Having a valid role helps screen readers understand the structure of the page and allows them to quickly navigate to those items (such as 'H' to go to the next heading, 'L' for the next list, or 'T' for the next table.)  If your element does not have any semantic meaning, it does not need a role.

As a side note, there are cases where an element can have `tabindex="-1"` and have a valid role.  If I implement my own list selector using `<ul>/<li>`, where every list item is a choice but I want the entire list as a whole to be one tab stop, then I will have `tabindex="-1"` on all the list items except for the one I want to receive tab focus.  It will have `tabindex="0"`.  If I tab to the entire list, the focus will go to the item with `tabindex="0"`.  I can then arrow up/down through the list to make a different selection.  As I arrow up/down, I'm toggling the value of `tabindex` on the appropriate list item.

Comment: I have wrappel element of some inputs. I want to stop there on tab pressed. but  I set `tabindex="0"` it showing similer error.  But If I set `tabindex="-1"` it is focusable by mouse click but not focusable by keyboard tab button. so what to do in this case ?
I know you already said an answer but you didn't tell how to dismiss this warning in correct way.  (- _ - )

Comment: @HNazmulHassan, I would recommend you post a new question and tag it with `accessibility`. I don't really understand what you're asking in your comment.  If you have an <input>, then you don't need `tabindex` at all. It's natively focusable.  You mention an error but the original question nor my answer didn't talk about errors.